# Please Add Ignore Flag Button to Tools

Tags: feature-request, 10k-tools

Going through the Tools menu and flagging is a daily chore. It would be helpful if to the right of the Close Question button, there was an Ignore button.

The reason for this is that after perusing the flags and I have investigated the flag on whether I will (a) add additional flagging or (b) close the question - I choose to simply ignore it. Well, that question/answer still shows up in my Tools menu until a moderator handles it.

The only way to make it disappear from my Tools menu is to take action. The action I want to take is to tell it to go away, but I can't.

Before choosing Ignore, there should be a confirmation (2nd step) that you wish to actually Ignore. The reason is because I imagine this would be irreversible.

The other option is to make it a one click option (like Approve or Reject in the Edit menu) and then show another tab for Ignored posts.

Comment: FWIW, I prefer confirmation-less action with ability to undo actions over action confirmations every single time. But I would like this feature -- the original flagger might very well be correct, but I don't feel strongly enough to concur _or_ vote to invalidate the flag.

Comment: @sarnold: Yep, that's exactly what I am getting at.

Comment: are you referring to http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tools?s=1&tab=close&daterange=today ?

Comment: @JeffAtwood: Nope, not that page. I am talking about a button adjacent to "Flag or disagree" and "Close question".

Comment: @JeffAtwood, I second this - under the 10k flag tools ("Tools" and then "Flags," [here for gaming](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/tools?s=1&tab=flags&daterange=)) - the only way to get a flag off this list is to add my own flag, or deem the flags invalid.  Sometimes I don't have the expertise to determine if a flag is valid or not.  However, the flag stays on that list until it is cleared by a moderator or I take a stance on it.  I'd like an "ignore this" button so that it doesn't clutter up my flag list when I can't help with it.

Comment: I am fine with this, we can also get some extra stats/information about flags this way

Comment: I want this. Any news on this feature?